# Why wont my Strings compare?

Tags: java, function, if-statement

Ok, so I was assigned to make a Dice program that could be called to roll a dice and return the side it landed on. I got the Dice part of it done. However when I run my program, my `if` statement doesn't execute to increment `Counter` if both die equal `6`. What is wrong with my program.

**This is the main:**

```
public class PairOfDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Counter = 0;
        Dice D1 = new Dice();
        Dice D2 = new Dice();

        for (int X = 0; X <= 1000; X++)
        {
            D1.Roll();
            D2.Roll();

            if (D1.equals(6) && D2.equals(6))
            {
                Counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print ("Dice 1 = " + D1 + " | ");
                System.out.println ("Dice 2 = " + D2);
            }
        }
        System.out.print ("There were " + Counter + " Box Cars");
    }
}
```

**And this is my Dice function:**

```
public class Dice {

    private int Side;

    public Dice()
    {
        Roll();
    }

    public void Roll()
    {
        Side = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String A;
        A = Integer.toString(Side);
        return A;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would they? What do you think `D1.equals(6)` does? Why do you think so?

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: and your `Dice`is a class not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have missed what `.Equals()` means:

```
D1.equals(6)
```

`D1` doesn't equal `6`.  `D1` is an instance of a `Dice` object, and `6` is an integer.  You need to determine if the integer value *within* `D1` equals `6`.

First, create a getter for that value on the `Dice` class:

```
public int getSide()
{
    return Side;
}
```

Then use *that* in the comparisons:

```
if (D1.getSide() == 6 && D2.getSide() == 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the value of the die equals the value 6. Right now you are comparing the value of dice object to a number which doesn't make sense. Override equals or provide a getter for the value of the die.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out All I did was change `if (D1.equals(6) && D2.equals(6))` to `if (D1.equals(6) && D2.equals(6))` and removed the `else` part of the `if` statement, and put the print out before the `if` statement.

**This is the main:**

```
public class PairOfDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int Counter = 0;
        Dice D1 = new Dice();
        Dice D2 = new Dice();

        for (int X = 0; X <= 1000; X++)
        {
            D1.Roll();
            D2.Roll();

            System.out.print ("Dice 1 = " + D1 + " | ");
            System.out.println ("Dice 2 = " + D2);

            if (D1.Side == 6 && D2.Side == 6)
            {
                Counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print ("There were " + Counter + " Box Cars");
    }
}
```

**This is Dice:**

```
public class Dice {

    int Side;

    public Dice()
    {
        Roll();
    }

    public void Roll()
    {
        Side = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String A;
        A = Integer.toString(Side);
        return A;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be best to make `Side` a [private variable](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables) and use the getter method you created. Better yet you could make a new getter method that returns it as an integer. Either way make sure you hide the internal implementation of your class so that down the road another programmer's code doesn't break when you refactor the internals of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below logic

```
public class PairOfDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        Dice d1 = new Dice();
        Dice d2 = new Dice();

        for (int X = 0; X <= 1000; X++)
        {
            d1.roll();
            d2.roll();

            if (d1.getSide()==6 && d2.getSide()==6)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print ("Dice 1 = " + d1 + " | ");
                System.out.println ("Dice 2 = " + d2);
            }
        }
        System.out.print ("There were " + counter + " Box Cars");
    }
}




public class Dice {

    private int side;

    public Dice()
    {
        roll();
    }

    public void roll()
    {
        side = (int)(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String A;
        A = Integer.toString(side);
        return A;
    }

    public int getSide() {
        return side;
    }
}
```